# HDR Not Scaling Properly

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, hdri, filmic-blender

just had a quick question.  Should be a simple fix.  When I am trying to bring in HDRs for lighting, it seems to not be scaling or working properly.  I can't see the HDR in the background.  I have kind of fiddled around with it by trying to use texture coordinate and mapping in the world section of the node editor but nothing was working.  It appears that the HDR is still lighting my scene for the most part but it's all thrown off.  Here is a screenshot of what it looks like.  You'll notice there is some blue in the background, but that's not very helpful.  Also, you can see what the HDR looks like in the preview area on the properties editor.  Thanks for the help!

[image]